# Android App Chooser does not show up when trying to stream smb file

Tags: android, stream, smb

I try to stream a video file from a hdd recorder via the smb protocol to android.

"VPlayer" is able to play such files, now i tried to navigate to this file with my app, start an app chooser an select the VPlayer.

This is what i do in the onclick:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setType("video/*");
intent.setData(Uri.parse(share));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select video app"));
```

The share-String is:

```
smb://192.168.1.5/media/recordings/die_simpsons/2011-12-02.19.04.50.99.rec/001.vdr
```

The problem is that no chooser is popping up, only astro file manager with the smb plugin starts and crashes...

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

That's because Android is unable to deal with smb shares out of the box. If you change your uri to http://... then you ll see that you get the app chooser. But in this case the video player has to be able to read the video from a http stream and the the smb server has to be able to stream to http.

If this is not what and you want to play your video from an smb you have to write your own provider. This is a hell of a job and I can't help you with it.